# Struts action resubmission

Tags: jsp, struts2

Hi am design on page with strut action class with method. when I called method its done properly and got success result. But I have problem when I refresh what success page its again submit the previous page values in database. how to avoid this one.

my first jsp page form

```
<form name="manualorder" action="manual_order" onsubmit="return validation();">
```

**struts.xml**

```
 <action name="purchaseorder" class="materialTypeMasterAction" method="createorder" >
    <result name="success">/pages/procurement/PurchaseOrder.jsp</result>
    </action>



    <action name="manual_order" class="materialTypeMasterAction" method="enquiry_process">
    <result name="success">/pages/procurement/success.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

when i refresh this success page its again `call enquiry_process method` and submit previous value which i created in createorder method in action first one.

Comment: Use post-redirect-get.

Comment: You need to use redirect action

Comment: When you refresh page ..current action is materialTypeMasterAction thats why probelm occures

Answer (score 3):

YOu can solve your problem using redirect action.
Just change your struts file as below ( i have added one more action for success:

```
<action name="purchaseorder" class="materialTypeMasterAction" method="createorder" >
    <result name="success">/pages/procurement/PurchaseOrder.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="SuccessAction" class="SuccessPage">

  <result name="success">/pages/procurement/success.jsp</result>
```

```
<action name="manual_order" class="materialTypeMasterAction" method="enquiry_process">
        <result type="redirectAction">SuccessAction</result>
</action>
```

Please do not forget to create `SuccessPage` class

Comment: Use `redirectAction` instead of `redirect-action`.

Comment: I am using redirect-action, there is no problem

Comment: @ButaniVijay Since Struts 2.2.1 `redirect-action` is deprecated. Use `redirectAction` for this result type.

Answer (score 0):

use **[post-redirect-get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)**.

On success, redirect to the `"success"` page. That way if the user refreshes, they just get that same page again.

See this link [Preventing Form Resubmission (due refreshing)](http://sothaticanremember.blogspot.in/2008/07/preventing-form-resubmission-due.html) and also see [Preventing Double Form Submission](http://dev.anyframejava.org/docs.en/anyframe/plugin/optional/struts/1.0.1/reference/html/ch10.html)
This may help you

Comment: @user3805315  I have updated my answer and added one link that link may help you

Comment: after redirect success.jsp. i try to refresh that success.jsp page that time its happen. what ever that jsp page give in <result> if i refresh that page it will submit duplicate values.